# Stop getting input with gets when specific character, similar chomp

Tags: ruby

In ruby I can stop getting inputs with:

```
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello my name is " + name
```

How can I stop getting the input when a user types in `END`.
For example:

```
I hate it to write END
```

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding something. The input is terminated by the new line character that the user inputs. There is nothing to do with `chomp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is terminated by the new line character that the user inputs. On standard console, you cannot terminate the input in other ways.

If you really want to do that introducing some heavy mechanism, then you should use [curses](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html), and particularly use `getch`.

Comment: Thanks but one more question! If i simply execute my programm with `name = gets.chomp` and type in `I love you \n` I does not break into a new line. Means it does not stop getting input! What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith I cannot understand your question in the comment.

Comment: Ok so far as i know the characters for a new line are `"\n"` thats what chomp looks for. Now instead of pressing the input key i tried to wirte `"\n"` into my console. But it didnt worked! It first stopped when i pressed the input key!

Comment: If you type `\n` in the terminal, that would be a backslash followed by `n`, in other words, a string `"\\n"`, which is distinct from `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
puts while gets.chomp != "END"
```